# php mysql database not updating

Tags: confirmation

can you check my code..my database wont update....when you click the confirm user..the database is not updating..i need help..please

```
 <?php
include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    if($_POST['status']=='confirmed')
    {
        $uid=$_POST['id'];
        $sql_update=mysql_query("UPDATE `tmc` SET `status`='confirmed' WHERE (`mem_id`='$uid')");
    }
}
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member WHERE status='pending'");

echo "<table>";
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $id=$result['mem_id'];
    $username=$result['username'];
    echo "<tr>
            <td>
                ".$id."
            </td>
            <td>
                ".$username."
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href='?id=".$id."&status='confirmed''>Confirm User</a>
            </td>
        </tr>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Could you append your connection.php file?

Comment: you send `status` parameter with `GET` method but you trying to catch its value with `POST` method.

Comment: I hope for your sake this isn't anywhere near the public internet because it's terrifyingly insecure. None of your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)! Remember, `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: $mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "0011";
$mysql_database = "tmc";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");

Comment: please guys..help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
....

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    if($_GET['status']=='confirmed')
    {
        $uid=$_GET['id'];
        $sql_update=mysql_query("UPDATE `tmc` SET `status`='confirmed' WHERE (`mem_id`='$uid')");
    }
}

....
```